# recaptcha 2 returns false but still submits fom

Tags: jquery, ajax, return, recaptcha

I curently am trying to stop the form from submitting if the recaptcha returns false, which it does but it still submits the form. I have used e.preventDefault as well and that isn't working so must be something not quite right.

Thanks in advance for your help.

JQUERY:

```
submit: function() {
$form = $('#registration-form');
$form.submit(function (e) {
$output = _validate($form);
  if($output == false) {
    e.preventDefault(e);
  } else {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "http://" + window.location.hostname + "/wp-content/themes/Listex/includes/plugins/forms/recaptcha.php",
      async: false,
      data: "g-recaptcha-response=" + grecaptcha.getResponse(),
      success: function(response) {
        alert(response);
        if (response == "false")
          return false;
      }
    });
}
});
```

},

recaptcha.php:

```
    <?php

$secret="secret code";
$response = $_POST["g-recaptcha-response"];

$verify=file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret={$secret}&response={$response}");
$captcha_success = json_decode($verify);

echo json_encode($captcha_success->success);
```

Comment: You can't return anything from an asynchronous callback function

Comment: sorry thats something I saw on stackoverflow and tried still doesn't work without

Answer (score 0):

Sorted in the end linked it in with current validation:

jQuery:

```
if(output == true) {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      async: false,
      url: "http://" + window.location.hostname + "/wp-content/themes/Listex/includes/plugins/forms/recaptcha.php",
      data: {
        //THIS WILL TELL THE FORM IF THE USER IS CAPTCHA VERIFIED.
        captcha: grecaptcha.getResponse()
      },
      success: function( data ) {
        console.log("FORM SUCCESSFUL");
        output = data;
      },
    });

  }

  if ( !output ) alert( 'Please ensure all required fields have been entered' );

  return output;
```

recaptcha.php:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['captcha']) && !empty($_POST['captcha'])){

$secret="6Lej1CkUAAAAAP0ACyvliPJo7Tp5I2eH52C-rsfG";
$response = $_POST["captcha"];

$verify = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret={$secret}&response={$response}");
$captcha_success = json_decode($verify);

echo json_encode($captcha_success->success);

}
?>
```